# convert swift to java?

Tags: java, ios, xcode, swift

I recently started programming and I started with swift which I now think was a bad idea because only ios uses it and it's pretty new. Anyways, I have an app that id like to port to android. Is my only option learning java? Or is there something that could help me?

Comment: You can use Swift to write MacOS applications as well. Regardless what you choose to do, you will need to probably rewrite most of the app in the language supported by the device you are targeting (so you won't be able to convert Java to Swift/ObjectiveC for example). You could consider looking at something like Project Codename One, which is Java based API which can be compiled to native iOS/Androd/Windows phone/etc, but this is an abstract action API, so some core functionality might be missing

Comment: Unfortunately a programmer cannot know "one language", you have to know "all languages".  A programmer knowing "one language" would be like a truck driver who can "only drive on one road".

Comment: @Fattie, maybe more like a truck driver that knows how to drive only one model of truck.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes. In that case you'd have to learn Java. But you could also try to use a language which supports Android and iOS. For example if you want to develop games you can use something like [ActionScript 3](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/actionscript/learning.html) with [Starling](http://gamua.com/starling/) and Adobe Air.

The pro point there is that you have to learn just one language and it's like a hybrid which works on both platforms.

In my opinion I would recommend you to learn Java as your second language, because it's always nice to know more than one programming language. That way you are much more openminded.